# Prevent session timeout using javascript

Tags: javascript, timeout, session-timeout

I have write some javascript code in my application to prevent sessions timeouts for a specific type of user. The timeout is controlled by server. How shuld I do this?

Comment: We need more information about the server, I think. Are you writing server code as ASP? JSP? PHP? etc.

Answer (score 4):

Make a call to the server that hits some page that updates the session.

```
function ping() {
     var img = new Image();
     img.src = "somePage.php?ts=" + (new Date()).getTime();
     window.setTimeout(ping,60*1000);
}
```

You could make an an Ajax call instead of an image request.

Comment: You can ask to user(by confirm) here if he want to update or not (be idle)... Because this will never do Session time out..